# SciFi story about a world in intellectual darkness suddenly becoming enlightened when a filter covering the sun is removed

Tags: story-identification

I think this is a short story. It opens with a rabbit in a cage, stuck there. Then suddenly there is a change of light -- like the sun coming out of an eclipse, or a film or filter being removed that allows a more pure sunlight to shine on the world. People and animals are suddenly more intelligent. The rabbit figures out how to open its cage and escape. This enlightened condition lasts for a short while and then the eclipse or filter or film covering the sun returns and the world is plunged back into intellectual darkness.

Comment: Sounds a lot like Poul Anderson's "Brain Wave", but that was a novel, not a short story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall when or where you read this?

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt: sounds a little like brainwave. the filter is actually a giant "cloud" which slows down light -- maybe the OP is misremembering. was there a rabbit in brainwave? there were other animals, some of which reach human or superhuman intelligence when their "IQs" quintuple.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt there may have been a shorter version of Brain Wave. I have it in one of those old big collections (A treasury of great sf volume 2). It has the rabbit.

Comment: @releseabe The rabbit scene is the first paragraph in _Brainwave_!

Comment: Thanks.  I no longer have a copy of this one to refer to.

Answer (score 18):

This has to be [Brain Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Wave) by Poul Anderson. It opens with the scene you remember:

> The trap had closed at sundown. In the last red light, the rabbit had battered himself against its walls until fear and numbness ached home and he crouched shaken by the flutterings of his heart.
> ...
> The rabbit crouched, bracing his shoulders against the crossbar. He strained then, heaving upward, and the wood shivered. The rabbit’s breath came fast and sharp, whistling between his teeth, and he tried again. The gate moved upward in its grooves, and the rabbit bolted free.

This is a novel not a short story, but it was [first published as a novella](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?537965) called *The Escape* in the magazine Space Science Fiction, and that may be what you are remembering.

The cloud does not return at the end, but there is a scene where a spaceship being piloted by the newly super intelligent humans accidentally flies back into the cloud. Maybe that is what you are remembering, or it's possible you have conflated it with another story.

*Brain Wave* is a well known novel that has been discussed here [many times already](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D%20-%5Bmanga%5D%20-%5Bmovie%5D%20-%5Btv%5D%20-%5Banime%5D%20-%5Bcartoon%5D%20brain%20wave%20anderson).